# `wp_delete_post` returns NULL

Tags: wp-delete-post

I am trying to delete a lot of WordPress posts programmatically using `wp_delete_post`, but not all posts are deleted successfully. In some cases I get `NULL` as a return value for
`wp_delete_post($row->post_id, true)` and the post isn't deleted from the database.

There are both `post` and `page` post_types amongst those not deleted posts, as well as custom post types.

What can be the issue there, why aren't some posts deleted, while many others are deleted successfully?

Comment: Skimming wp_delete_post (and wp_trash_post, which is called for posts and pages but not custom types) and wp_delete_attachment, the only places they return null are when they can't find the post by ID e.g. [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.7/wp-includes/post.php#L3087).

Comment: Where are you getting the IDs from. Are you sure they exist?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, those are posts of a specific language that I want to delete. I get them with `get_posts` function. And yes, I'm sure they exist in my `wp_*_posts` table. My WordPress is a multisite, so I have several wp_*_posts` tables. I am not sure if that matters, but anyway.

Comment: If you're trying to delete posts from another site's posts table by ID, then that's not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I was trying to delete a post while my current site wasn't the same one. My WordPress is multisite.

`switch_to_blog($siteId);` solved the issue.